# How to make Chrome use favicon.ico at 16x16 instead of SVG?

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I have the following in my HTML `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16" /> 
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
```

Chrome on Windows 10 shows the SVG icon in preference to the ICO.
I don't want this behaviour, as the SVG icon looks blurry at small sizes.
My ".ico" file is pixel perfect at 16 x 16, which is the exact size of the icon in my Chrome tab.
How can I make Chrome choose the ".ico" over the SVG?

If I remove the reference to the SVG, Chrome uses the ".ico", but I'd like browsers to be able to use the SVG on higher resolution screens.

I tried this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16" /> 
<link rel="alternate icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
```

And I also tried removing the "sizes" attribute, but nothing I've done has made a difference.

I'm using Chrome 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (64-bit), but I need an answer that works more generally than just my browser.

Comment: What about Chrome on high-res screens? You seem to have two conflicting criteria.

Comment: Why would a svg look blurry, maybe you can optimize the SVG a bit to show good on small sizes. Maybe you have some values in the SVG that result in half pixels if scaled down and that's what makes it look off. I would try to optimize the SVG.

Comment: @cloned The favicon I've designed for 16 x 16 is a slightly simplified version of the SVG. I don't want to be forced to position things in my SVG so they fit with a 16 x 16 grid.

Comment: @isherwood, I don't think it's conflicting. That is why I stated `sizes="16x16"`. If the pixel size is 16x16 then use the ".ico". If the pixel size for the icon is 32x32 (or whatever), on a high-res screen, then use the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if I add a second 32x32 bitmap image to the "favicon.ico" file (".ico" format can contain multiple sizes in one file) and I change the `sizes` attribute as follows:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="16x16 32x32" />
```

Then Chrome chooses the ".ico" instead of the SVG and uses the 16x16 ".ico" image.